# Cannot implement autocomplete from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am struggling to implement autocomplete on my page as no results are showing from the database.

Below is the code on the index.php page

```
<head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: "autocomplete.php"
            });
        });
    </script> </head> <body> <label for="tags">Select Student</label> <div><input id="tags" type="text" name="tags"  /> </div></body>
```

The autocomplete.php file looks like this...

```
<?php include("session.php"); 
session_start(); 
$description_arr = array(); 
$stmt =  "select case 
          When (login.name is null or login.name='') and (login.surname is null or login.surname='') 
          then login.username 
          Else login.name + ' ' + login.surname 
          End as user_profile 
          from my_students 
          inner join login 
          on stud_id = login.id 
          where my_students.id = '$login_id'";
$ses_stmt = mysqli_query($conn, $stmt); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_stmt)){ 
array_push($description_arr,$row['user_profile']);} 
echo json_encode($description_arr); 
?>
```

Comment: And do you get an error on your return? Or no return? It's a bit difficult without some informations.

Comment: In the future please format code so it is readable. If you can't read it we can't. Does the `autocomplete.php` work if accessed directly? Where is `$login_id` set? This looks to be injectable, you should be parameterizing. Have you used the `+` for concatenation in mysql before? I use `concat` function `concat(login.name, ' ',  login.surname)`, I thought `+` was only for math.

Comment: @RenéHöhle. I do not get an error, there is simply nothing returned when I type in the input field.

Comment: @user3783243. autocomplete.php works fine when accessed directly, and adding two strings together in this way is perfectly legal in sql.

Comment: Perhaps you get a CORS error in your browser? That blocks your request? Or do you see the request and it's empty?

Comment: @RenéHöhle. It is not a CORS error,. The weird thing is that I'm outputting the same information in a list so the request is not being blocked. I'm not sure what you mean by being able to see the request?

Comment: Open the developer console in your browser and go to the `network` tab.